# Appengine Wordpress tutorial app fails on wp-admin handler

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I went through the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

I have a site up and running but I can't reach any urls including wp-admin.

The following handlers are in place as per the tutorial.

```
- url: /wp-admin/(.+)  
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1  
  secure: always  

- url: /wp-admin/  
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php  
  secure: always
```

The logs show this error:

> 2013-11-16 17:03:26.656 /wp-admin/ 500 41ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36 module=default version=wp1
>   108.16.36.126 - - [16/Nov/2013:14:03:26 -0800] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36" "time-o-radar.appspot.com" ms=42 cpu_ms=0 exit_code=204 app_engine_release=1.8.7 instance=00c61b117c1c4c05e09fb99796031b9cdc0dd28f
>   W 2013-11-16 17:03:26.655
>   A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)

Where can I look to discover what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling myself to get that working on custom domain. Seems no matter what I put, like secure: never, /wp-admin/ urls always get redirected by App Engine to https:// using SSL protocol, which results in error if you're using custom domain.

But you are able to access your backend if you set site URL to your https://app-name.appspot.com

That way you can access wp admin backend https://app-name.appspot.com/wp-admin/
but still server site from custom domain on the front end.

Unfortunately this approach renders all inside URLs pointing to http://app-name.appspot.com, but I get around this with "Relative URL" plugin which removes absolute path on all HTML source code URLs.

I also found out few missing URL handlers from whatever google describes in their app.yaml sample for WordPress sites, like:

- url: /wp-comments-post.php
  script: wordpress/wp-comments-post.php

was not included therefore visitors were unable to post comments.